# How to make a “asp:Button” work inside a “mmenu nav “

Tags: c#, .net, mmenu

I’m trying to integrate “jquery.mmenu” in a Visual Studio project.
It seems that “asp:Button” does not work inside a “mmenu nav “.
Nor a "asp:LinkButton" seems to fully perform.
Take the specific case of a login:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="test._default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.mmenu.min.all.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/themes/base/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/themes/base/jquery.mmenu.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title></title>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#login").mmenu({
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <a href="#login">Open login pannel</a><br />
            <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LoginText="login" LogoutText="logout" LogoutPageUrl="~/" /><br />

            <nav id="login">
                <div>
                    <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server">User:</asp:Label><br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserNameTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server">Password:</asp:Label><br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="PasswordTextBox" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox><br />
                    <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Login Button" OnClick="LoginButton_Click" /><br />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LoginLinkButton" runat="server"  ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="LoginLinkButton_Click">Login LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The code behind looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace test
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(UserNameTextBox.Text, PasswordTextBox.Text))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserNameTextBox.Text, false);
            }
        }

        protected void LoginLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(UserNameTextBox.Text, PasswordTextBox.Text))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserNameTextBox.Text, false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The asp:Button does not post back.
The asp:LinkButton does not login.
Is there a way to have it working?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Web forms most of the time change the name of the element and jquery needs the exact name to find your button. Add this property to your button and test again

ClientIDMode="Static"

Comment: Whats do you want the asp button to do?

Comment: Maybe with a link button

Comment: The button don't have the event related in your post.

Comment: Nope. Nothing seems to work. I've edit the question trying to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

The mmenu plugin grabs the NAV#login from the HTML and puts it back directly inside the BODY. Meaning, the input and button are no longer inside the FORM (and thus won't submit the form).

Basically, if you put the FORM inside the NAV#login all should work as expected.